# Find the respective top-level element for each bottom element in a hierarchical table

Tags: sql, hierarchy

I am trying to query a table that represents hierarchical data to find the top-level element for each bottom element. Here, an example:

```
ID    PARENTID               
----- --------  
1     1
2     1
3     2
4     2
5     3
6     6
7     6
8     6
9     4
10    10
```

I want to have a query that returns the ID of the lowest elements in the hierarchy along with the ultimate Parent for that ID. So, the result should look like this:

```
ID    UltimateParentID               
----- ----------------  
5     1
7     6
8     6
9     1
10    10
```

Is there a way to get this result with a recursive SQL query?

So far, I couldn't find any SQL code that fits my needs.

Comment: Please share what you've tried to resolve the problem, and which database system you want to use. There are a lot of other questions of this type on StackOverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with rec(root, id, parentid, lvl) as (
  select id, id, parentid, 1 from t 
  where not exists (select 1 from t x where parentid = t.id and parentid <> id)
  union all
  select rec.root, t.id, t.parentid, rec.lvl + 1 
  from rec join t on rec.parentid = t.id and t.id <> t.parentid)
select root, parentid 
from (
  select root, parentid, lvl, max(lvl) over (partition by root) mxl from rec) r
where lvl = mxl
```

Demo for: [SQL Server](https://dbfiddle.uk/sXM2T02F) and for [Oracle](https://dbfiddle.uk/fKjS4ZcS)

It is almost classic recursive query except facts that you have rows like (6, 6) and (10, 10) causing cycles, so we have to eliminate them in processing. Last part with analytic max() is used to find leaf (ultimate) rows,

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH RECURSIVE r AS (
  SELECT
    h.id AS ultimate_parentid
  , h.id::VARCHAR AS recpath
  , h.id
  , h.parentid
  FROM h
  WHERE h.parentid = h.id
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT
    p.ultimate_parentid AS ultimate_parentid
  , p.recpath||'->'||c.id::VARCHAR(5) AS recpath
  , c.id
  , c.parentid
  FROM r AS p
  JOIN h AS c ON p.id = c.parentid
  WHERE c.parentid <> c.id
)
SELECT
  *
FROM r
ORDER BY recpath
;
```

| ultimate_parentid | recpath | id | parentid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1->2 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 1->2->3 | 3 | 2 |
| 1 | 1->2->3->5 | 5 | 3 |
| 1 | 1->2->4 | 4 | 2 |
| 1 | 1->2->4->9 | 9 | 4 |
| 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 |
| 6 | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| 6 | 6->7 | 7 | 6 |
| 6 | 6->8 | 8 | 6 |